# What is the "thread incarnation of the Other"?

Tags: girl-genius

The Girl Genius wiki, in a footnote to its [article on the Other](http://girlgenius.wikia.com/wiki/The_Other), makes  an extremely cryptic reference:

> WOG on a thread incarnation of the other.

This suggests that Kaja or Phil Foglio at some point said something about an form of the Other with some link to thread. Nonetheless, this is quite vague.

Unfortunately, the included link is defunct, and does not appeared to have been archived. A web search turns up nothing.

What is meant by "a thread incarnation of the Other"? The word "thread" is mentioned both in the footnote and its referent, so it is not likely to be a misspelling.

Comment: I can think of no possibilities where this is not a typo of some kind. We know there are multiple copies of the Other here on Earth, we know they get "downloaded" from somewhere else so thats one more, and then theres whatever Zola is (rogue Other?). This might refer to the D/L version, i just don't know how.

Comment: Alternatively, this would be a copy we'd know nothing about - and then this cant really be answered.  I'll see if i can find anything  this original source

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**A total unknown.**

The references to "thread" in that wiki article appear starting in an edit dated Oct 16th 2010. The comments for that edit states "added link to interviu whear Phil tell us about a thread other that we hawent seen yet". So this is referencing info that is not in the comic at all.

To double down on the unknown, the source link is not only to a dead site, it's also supposed to be mp3 audio of the author interview in question. There's not likely to be any archived copy, and my searches have turned up no other references.

So there is no other info except "someone says the author said this once".

Comment: No, I suspect it really is some sort of thread clank. Like a living doll or something.

Comment: @Adamant You mean ragdoll physics in the most absurd fashion I presume? Still not out of scope for this setting, but also still nothing i can find. I even went through other interviews w/ Phoglio round the same time. Nada. I presume the recording was some chatter at a signing event or a con booth. Whatever. The Other is still a weird mystery, and until wacky hilarity with dead zombie kings clears up, there's no progress on it.

Comment: Well, Comic-Con is in two weeks, the Foglios will be there, and (I presume) some of our noted users will be there. That would be an excellent opportunity for an answer to this question. Alternately, someone could contact one of the Wikia users who made those edits. If someone successfully did *both*, there'd definitely be a bounty for them.